# Disable Binary Caching for the CUDA compiler driver

Tags: cuda, gpu, opencl, gpgpu, jit

I noticed that CUDA/OpenCL compilation times through the compiler driver (Driver Version: *440.64*) are up 10x faster after the first compilation of a kernel. 
Thus, the driver caches the generated binary instead of compiling every time and retrieves it from a code cache.

Is there a way to ...

1. disable binary caching and force compilation in every run?
2. to access information about the cached binaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Nvidia documentation this can be solved with JIT caching options [CUDA Pro Tip: Understand Fat Binaries and JIT Caching](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-understand-fat-binaries-jit-caching/)

1. Exporting the following enviromental variable prevents JIT caching
   and forces compilation on every run: `export CUDA_CACHE_DISABLE=1`
2. On Linux all cache files are stored in: `~/.nv/ComputeCache`